# Securing a Node Red GUI on IBM WATSON Cloud

Tags: ibm-cloud, node-red

I've got a Node-RED Dashboard running on Bluemix, but I want to secure it using the standard Node-RED security, i.e., editing the `settings.js` file.

Does anyone know how I can actually access this on BlueMix?

Answer (score 2):

On the IBM Cloud dashboard for your application you need to enable the Continuous Delivery feature. That will get you a git repository containing the application code which you can edit in your browser and have changes automatically deploy back into your running application.

You will then need to edit the file called `bluemix-settings.js` to add the required settings to secure the Node-RED dashboard.